# Inequality mod p for all primes implies equality.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$, $m$ positive ($n,m>0$) integers such that $n \le m\bmod{p}$ for all primes $p$, prove that $n=m$. To clarify, the above inequality is taken using the representatives $\{0,1...,p-1\}$ of the class of remainders modulo $p$

Comment: $n\le m\bmod p$ is not well-defined, because $n\equiv n-p\bmod p$. If you restrict to the representatives, then you shouldn't write $n\le m\bmod p$.

Comment: Do you mean $\{0,1,2,3,\cdots, p-1\}$?

Comment: @lulu Yes, my bad, it's now edited.

Comment: Quick remark:  suppose we had a counterexample, with $n<m$.  Then any prime $p$ which divides $m$ must also divide $n$ (else that prime $p$ would violate your condition).

Comment: Take $n=10$ and $m=12$, then $n\leq m$ but the inequality is false using their representatives modulo 11

Comment: @PITTALUGA I think you misread the question, the implication is in the other direction.

Comment: @MartinOrtiz Yep sorry I read it too quickly ;)

Comment: Couldn't you prove it by contradiction?

Comment: What about $n=0, m=1?$

Comment: @gammatester $n,m$ must be positive.

Comment: @WillJagy I honestly don't know, someone told me the problem some time ago and I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: @Peter: For me (and others)  $0$ is positive. To remove ambiguity the question should use $n,m > 0$.

Comment: In the case $n\ge 2$ and $m=2n$, Bertrand's postulate allows a proof. There exist a prime $p$ with $n<p<m$. Now, we have $2p>2n=m$, hence $m\mod p=m-p=2n-p=n+(n-p)<n=n\mod p$.

Comment: If a counterexample exists , we must have $m>10^7$

Comment: An argument similar to lulu's argument : If $n<m$ form a counterexample, then every prime dividing $n+1$ must also divide $m+1$

Comment: So far I've shown if we have a solution $(a,m)$ then we know $(b,m)$ with $a+b=m$ is also a solution (and thanks to @Peter, we also know $a\neq b$).

Answer (score 0):

We will prove the contrapositive; if $m > n$ (the case $m < n$ is rather trivial), then there is a prime $p$ such that $m \pmod{p} < n \pmod{p}$.

If $m \le 2n$, then one of $n+1, n+2, .., m$, let's say $n+a$, is divisible by a prime $p > m-n$, by [Sylvester's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Sylvester's_theorem). Then $m \pmod{p} = m-(n+a) < p-a$, while $n \pmod{p}$ either equals $n$ (if $p > n$) or it equals $p-a$ (if $p < n$). Since $n = (n+a) -a \ge p-a$, in both cases we get $m \pmod{p} < p-a \le  n \pmod{p}$.

If $m \ge 2n$, then, again by Sylvester's Theorem, one of $m-n+1, m-n+2, .., m$ is divisible by a prime $p > n$. In this case $m \pmod{p} < n = n \pmod{p}$.

There is also a short note [here](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1987-01.pdf?fbclid=IwAR1xcYik40nFYBc0WItcEz0fRmxQD4NHMdKT4aZKA60P9vKvVdiom7cWuvc) detailing a different, self-contained proof by Szegedy.